# Difference between .pb and .h5

Tags: tensorflow, keras

What is the main difference between .**pb** format of tensorflow and **.h5** format of keras to store models? Is there any reason to choose one over the other?

Answer (score 29):

Different file formats with different characteristics, both used by `tensorflow` to save models (`.h5` specifically by `keras`).

## `.pb` - protobuf

It is a way to store some structured data (in this case a neural network),project is [open source](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf) and currently overviewed by Google.

### Example

```
person {
  name: "John Doe"
  email: "jdoe@example.com"
}
```

Simple `class` containing two fields, you can load it in one of multiple supported languages (e.g. `C++`, `Go`), parse, modify and send to someone else in binary format.

### Advantages

- really small and efficient to parse (when compared to say `.xml`), hence often used for data transfer across the web
- used by [Tensorflow's Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving) when you want to take your model to production (e.g. inference over the web)
- language agnostic - binary format can be read by multiple languages (Java, Python, Objective-C, and C++ among others)
- advised to use since `tf2.0` , you can see [official serializing guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize)
- saves various metadata (optimizers, losses etc. if using `keras`'s model)

### Disadvantages

- `SavedModel` is conceptually harder to grasp than single file
- creates folder where `weights` are

### Sources

You can read about this format [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview)

## `.h5` - HDF5 binary data format

Used originally by `keras` to save models (`keras` is now officially part of `tensorflow`). It is less general and more "data-oriented", less programmatic than `.pb`.

### Advantages

- Used to save giant data (so some neural networks would fit well)
- Common file saving format
- Everything saved in one file (weights, losses, optimizers used with `keras` etc.)

### Disadvantages

- Cannot be used with `Tensorflow Serving` but you can simply convert it to `.pb` via `keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, 'path_to_saved_model')`

## All in all

Use the simpler one (`.h5`) if you don't need to productionize your model (or it's reasonably far away). Use `.pb` if you are going for production or just want to standardize on single format across all `tensorflow` provided tools.