# How should I save my machine learning model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

I`m here to ask if there is any difference in saving my model as **.h5** or **.model**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your **created_model.model** you can find file with **.pb**

So you want to know difference between **.h5** and **.pb**

There is, what you want: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079274/difference-between-pb-and-h5)